# How convert ByteArray string to NEO address in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, cryptography, base58

I analyze transactions with the InvocationTransaction type using the getplicationlog and get a data array in response

```
array(2) {
    ["type"]=> string(9) "ByteArray"
    ["value"]=> string(40) "0631901fb121f633fa496d3689649a06628f63c8"
}
```

Help me, how to convert ByteArray to an NEO address in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure, but you can try to use [convBase()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#106546) function submitted by user in php.net. Usage is like:

```
echo 
  convBase(
   "0631901fb121f633fa496d3689649a06628f63c8", // hex data 
   "0123456789ABCDEF", // hex alphabet
   "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz"); // base58 alphabet
```

Output:

> 61Gh7hAAzfnmUqVvE5najukwNBq

But I have some doubts that your hex data may be truncated or passed to some additional compression/encryption scheme, because typical NEO address when converted to base16 holds
 `25 bytes` and you have only `20 bytes` - so there must be something else going on